# Convert python file to .exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, py2exe

I'm trying to make executable Tkinter file with photos, video and two songs using pyinstaller. I've done it without pictures, but I don't know how to connect them in the exe file. Is it possible using pyinstaller, or I need to use some other module? I am using python 3.8.2

Comment: your python script has them linked right?just make an exe with `pyinstaller` and then run it,from where the path is correct

Comment: I replaced the .exe file in the folder with the python script and the image and it worked (The script contained only one image as a test). Still can't make it run with audio, it says "Failed to execute script playmusic" (playmusic is the name of the script).

Comment: Audio? Is the audio in the right destination as mentioned in your script?

Comment: Yes, everything is placed right. When I run the script from VS Code it runs without problems.

Comment: Have you move the exe from the `dist` folder to the script directory?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. It displays the same message

Comment: What message? If you don't use `-w` and say `-c` instead, it will open up a console on which the error message will be printed. That should be included with the code above

Answer (score 1):

PyInstaller won't do such a thing. You need to provide your sound files manually. First, you need to add your sound files to the output executable with [add-data](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) flag then create a function to load your files from the extracted path

Comment: Can't you just edit the spec file to include the external files? https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html

Comment: it says "Failed to execute script playmusic"